# Can't modify an Excel File using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, excel, vba

I have a winform application where I read a XML invoice, get the order number of it and then insert it into an Excel file previously loaded with the list of invoices(a way to locally keep track of them) updating the row.

I used to do it for 97-2003 Worksheets, and it worked just fine. But since our users prefer working on 2013 Worksheets I started working on modifying the connection string to work with it.

I also had to install Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components  2007 so it could work with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

When I run it I get the following exception:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbExeption (0x80004005): The Microsoft Office Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.

Which is odd since I'm currently working locally. Currently only two users use this application, and they were able to work with it by just sharing the file.

I'm a bit stuck with this, I've been reading for more info about this but I haven't been successful, when I just look for the exception results say that it's about a *not found* file. And when I look for the exception text I don't get results for my particular case.

I've debugged the code but I didn't get much information, since everything runs fine until it hits the exception. Which is basically what I show up in a `MessageBox`.

### Anyone has knowledge as to why this might be happening?

**Code:**

```
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.xlsx;" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes\";";
            MyConnection = new       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql = "Update [sheetname$] set OrderNumber= @order where Invoice= @invoice";
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order", orderNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice", invoiceNumber);
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Why did somebody vote to close this? Odd, to say the least.

Comment: PPR, is this "ACE" for Ace Reports, of Illinois? If so, I know that cat, and I'm sure he'd be glad to help you.

Comment: I don't know, then, what the "ACE" in "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" stands for.

Comment: stands for "Office Access Connectivity Engine" @B.ClayShannon

Comment: Is it possible that you have another instance of your code that is still running?  This happens sometimes while debugging.  Check TaskManager for another instance.

Comment: Yes, there was another instance running; after terminating it everything worked fine. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it @DavidTansey , I always forget to check the most obvious/logic reasons, I guess I was too tilted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I encounter this error or similar errors during debugging, I have a soft-assumption that I am working in isolation (i.e. because it is all local, I am the only 'user' actively working with the artifacts/data etc), the problem usually ends up being that **I am also the 'other user'** that the error message is complaining about.

It is easy to inadvertently leave an instance of my code still executing when I am working through debugging cycles of DEBUG | TEST | Stop Debugging.  An orphaned instance of the code may well still have locks on various resources causing the problem you described.

Check in the Windows TaskManager to see if there are possibly one or more orphaned instances of your code / debug session.  Kill the orphaned tasks and the next DEBUG execution you start should be now be able to execute cleanly.